# Better explanation of conjugation of permutations?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, symmetric-groups

It says here that $\rho = \tau \sigma \tau^{-1}$, and if $\sigma(i) = j$, then $\rho(\tau(i)) = \tau(j)$. So take for example $\sigma = (1 3 2 4) (5 6)$ and $\rho = (5 2 3 1)(6 4)$. To find $\tau$, it says that you can just line up $\sigma$ and $\rho$ like so $$\begin{array}{cccccc}
1&3&2&4&5&6\\
5&2&3&1&6&4
\end{array}$$
and take $\tau$ to be $(1 5 6 4)(2 3)$. I don't understand why lining up the permutations like this works in finding $\tau$, as it just looks like magic. The fact that $\rho(\tau(i)) = \tau(j)$ and $\rho = \tau \sigma \tau^{-1}$ doesn't seem to explain this phenomenon to me, while textbooks/online resources just brush it off as obvious as a result of the aforementioned equations, so is there an intuitive explanation for why this works?

i.e. If $\sigma(a_1) = a_2$, then $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1} (\tau(a_1)) = \tau(a_2)$. Why does this imply that $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1} = (\tau(a_1) \tau(a_2) ...)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\sigma,\tau$ be a permutations on $\{1,\ldots, n\}$.  If $\sigma$ is a cycle, say $\sigma=(i_1,\ldots i_k)$, then

$$\begin{align}
\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}(\tau(i_j)) & = \tau\sigma(i_j)\\
& = \tau(i_{j'})\\
\end{align}$$
where
$$j'=\begin{cases}j+1, & 1\le j<k\\1, & j=k\end{cases}.$$

So,
$$\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}=(\tau(i_1)\tau(i_2)\ldots\tau(i_k)).$$

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand where the $(\tau(i_1) \tau(i_2) ... \tau(i_k))$ comes from. You first have $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1} (\tau(i_j))$ but then you drop the $(\tau(i_j))$ term to get $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1}$. I don't see how that happens as well

Comment: @morphic saying $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}=(\tau(i_1),\tau(i_2),\ldots,\tau(i_k))$ means that $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}$ cycles $\tau(i_1)\to\tau(i_2)\to\cdots\to\tau(i_k)\to\tau(i_1)$ and fixes everything else. Tim has explained why $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}$ cycles these. You just need to convince yourself that everything else gets fixed.

Comment: @DavidHill the argument why $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1}$ cycles these is given as because $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1} (\tau(i_j)) = \tau(i_j')$ where $j'$ is stated as in the post. I don't see why $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1} (\tau(i_j)) = \tau(i_{j'}) \implies \tau \sigma \tau^{-1} = (\tau(i_1) \tau(i_2) ... \tau(i_k))$.

Comment: @morphic are you not sure that $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}(s)=s$ if $s\notin\{\tau(i_1),\ldots,\tau(i_k)\}$? For such an $s$, $\tau^{-1}(s)\notin\{i_1,\ldots,i_k\}$, so $\sigma(\tau^{-1}(s))=\tau^{-1}(s)$. Therefore $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}(s)=\tau\sigma(\tau^{-1}(s))=\tau(\tau^{-1}(s))=s$.

Comment: @morphic  Looks at David's first comment.  What does $(t(i_1)\ldots t(i_k))$ mean?

Comment: $(\tau(i_1) ... \tau(i_k))$ is a cycle, and $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1} (\tau(i_j))$ gives us an element of that cycle. But $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1}$ is not acting on any $(\tau(i_j))$ element, so I see that $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1}$ is some cycle, but because there's no $(\tau(i_j))$ involved in the equation, I don't see how the resulting cycle is necessarily elements of the form $(\tau(i_j))$.

Comment: Why are you saying that $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}$ does not act on any $\tau(i_j))$?  $\tau(i_j)$ is an element of $\{1,\ldots, n\}$.

Comment: @morphic I think you need to think about this some more. Why don't you try a few examples. Say $\sigma=(1,2,3)$ and $\tau=(1,2)$, Then $(\tau(1),\tau(2),\tau(3))=(2,1,3)$. What is $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}$?

Comment: @DavidHill When I work out specific examples, of course everything works out fine. But I don't understand the intuitive reason of why all the examples work out to be correct in terms of the proposed question. In other words, it doesn't answer my question why it works. In going from $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}(\tau(i_j)) = \tau(i_{j'})$ to $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}=(\tau(i_1)\tau(i_2)\ldots\tau(i_k))$, I am having trouble understanding the steps in between those two steps.

Comment: @morphic Look $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}(\tau(i_1))=\tau(\sigma(\tau^{-1}(\tau(i_1))))=\tau(\sigma(i_1))=\tau(i_2)$. Does that help?

Comment: @DavidHill I understand this, but I don't understand the part without the $\tau(i_1)$. Like why $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1}$ is the cycle that contains all of the elements given by $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1} (\tau(i_j))$. I understand that each $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1} (\tau(i_j))$ gives us some one element, but I don't understand why $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1}$ is all of these elements put together in a permutation of cycles.

Comment: @morphic A permutation has $(c_1\cdots c_k)$ in its cycle decomposition if and only if it sends $c_j$ to $c_{j+1}$ for all $j\bmod k$. Since you know $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}$ sends $\tau(i_j)$ to $\tau(i_{j+1})$ for all $j\bmod k$, you know $(\tau(i_1)\cdots\tau(i_k))$ is a cycle in its cycle decomposition. Now prove it fixes everything not of the form $\tau(i_j)$, so there are no other cycles in its cycle decomposition. To prove this, use the fact that $\sigma$ fixes everything not of the form $i_j$.

Comment: @anon My issue here is the part when you say "$\tau \sigma \tau^{-1}$ sends $\tau(i_j)$ to $\tau(i_{j+1})$". I understand that $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1} \tau(i_j)$ sends $\tau(i_j)$ to $\tau(i_{j+1})$, but I don't understand why $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1}$ also sends $\tau(i_j)$ to $\tau(i_{j+1})$.

Comment: @morphic $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}\tau(i_j)$ doesn't send anything to anything, it's not even a function. If $f$ is a function, we say "$f$ sends $x$ to $y$" if $f(x)=y$. Now $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}$ is a function. I assume you can see that $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}$ applied to $\tau(i_j)$ yields $\tau(i_{j+1})$?

Comment: Oh, that actually clears my issue up. Thank you @anon